# Have Vegemite, Marmite and other yeast extracts been banned in Denmark?

Tags: nutrition, government, denmark

Have Vegemite, Marmite and other yeast extracts been banned in Denmark?

**Background**: I've heard this being claimed in the news, but there was a [false report](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegemite#Rumour_of_ban_in_United_States) of it being banned in the United States back in 2006.

Comment: Why would they ban marmite? I dont understand

Comment: @rmx: Was that sarcastic or serious?

Answer (score 11):

Denmark says the sale of Marmite or Vegemite [haven't been banned](http://www.uk.foedevarestyrelsen.dk/ImportExport/Legislation_on_import_of_food/Marmite_not_banned_in-Denmark.htm).

It states that foods fortified with vitamins, minerals or other substances, such as the abovementioned foods, can't be marketed unless Denmark's food authorities approve the products. The products in question haven't had marketing approval requested.

Comment: Vegemite *is* fortified with folate, so it would have to be approved. I think Vegemite has been like that for a long time, though.

Comment: @jozzas: Thanks for the clarification. I've edited the answer to be less confusing.

Comment: I'm almost certain I've seen Marmite for sale in the English store in Copenhagen.  Next time I'm in the city, I'll take a peek.

Comment: So, not banned, but you can't sell it?

Answer (score 3):

It hasn't been banned, it simply needs to apply for a license to be able to be sold.  Rice Crispies and other such fortified cereals have also had their license revoked, and have been asked to re-submit an application to be licensed for sale, due to the added minerals and bits and bobs.

Apparently, Marmite has been sold for ages without the correct license

Should this also state that they mean Marmite in england, as Aussie Marmite is different, with sugar and caramel added (for god knows what reason).

Some links:

[Marketing fortified food in Denmark](http://www.uk.foedevarestyrelsen.dk/Food_Safety/Fortified_food/forside.htm)

[Telegraph confirmation of license application needed](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/foodanddrink/foodanddrinknews/8537021/Marmite-makers-urged-to-fight-Denmark-ban.html)

Comment: Your answer doesn't have references. Someone might downvote you for that.

Comment: Interesting - the Telegraph article claims that an application for vegemite being sold had been rejected.